# Mongoose Query to search a document by name when name has any of a set o words no matter order

Tags: mongodb, search, mongoose, text

Imaging I have the following documents with these values:

```
{id: d,name: "pasta and chess"},{id: w,name: "pasta"},{id: 12,name: "chess"},{id: r,name: "chess and pasta"}
```

What could be a mongodb / mongoose query to get those documents containing both words: "pasta" and "chess" in its name field?, the order is not important, so I would expect the following result from that query:

```
[{id: d,name: "pasta and chess"},{id: r,name: "chess and pasta"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$and` operator to match both word and [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html) to match pattern,

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    { name: { $regex: "chess" } },
    { name: { $regex: "pasta" } }
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VdpR8ubwQUq)